# How do I encrypt a password in ODI 10g?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I'm using ODI 10g and I need to encrypt a password for using a specific action ?
It is not possible to fill a unencrypted password in the Designer.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a command line tool.

For example : under Windows, go to ODI installation directory and launch an agent with encode action.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\oracledi\oracledi\bin>agent encode mypassword
bSypMwVFsf99cHtQMofPp`

The action will return the encrypted password on the prompt.